# Why is Spotlight repeatedly re-indexing my disk?

Tags: macos, mac

About a week ago spotlight started reindexing my disk all of a sudden, without any provocation as far as I can tell. It took many hours to complete (MBA 1.8G i7 256ssd).

Then, today, again it started reindexing all over again. Only today, around the time that it started reindexing, I briefly got a low disk space warning and then immediately emptied the trash which accumulated many gigs -- this may or may not be related.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reindexing was probably just caused by running low on disk space. The same thing has happened to [some people at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21817/why-does-spotlight-keep-reindexing-my-system-after-updating-to-lion) and me a few times.